# What is the reference behind names "Alexander, Julian and Francis"?

Tags: science-fiction, junk-head

In Japanese science-fiction stop-motion movie "Junk Head", the protagonist meets three individuals named "Alexander, Julian and Francis".

It is surprising because all other characters do not have such traditional occidental names ("Hokuro", "Ponta", ...).

Are those three names a reference to some specific story, or an homage to some individuals?